# Hide title in Merlin Theme on posts and pages only

Tags: posts, css, title

I'm trying to figure out how to hide a post and page titles while on the specific post or page, but **NOT** throughout the entire site.

I've tried hiding the `.entry-title` class, but that hides titles globally. I only want the title hidden while viewing a single post or page.

For a reference, here is a link to the site I'm working on.
http://develop.warriorsoncataract.com/

Thanks!

Comment: Browsing the site is painful with the facebook like popup, how can someone like your sites content if they're asked before they get a chance to see it?

Answer (score 0):

Your theme correctly uses the `body_class` function, which you can see by looking at the body tag. This means CSS classes are being added such as `page` or `post` that you can work with.

e.g.

```
body.page .entry-title { display: none; }
```

There are many other CSS classes that may be useful to you, I suggest you browse your website with the developer tools turned on to see what CSS classes are available for styling